# How can I use org.eclipse.jface.text.PaintManager in subclass of TextEditor?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, jface

How can I attach a `PaintManager` to my `TextEditor`? 
For example, draw the background of cursor line with `org.eclipse.jface.text.CursorLinePainter`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your editor's `TextViewer` or `SourceViewer` provides the paint manager. You can access it using the `ITextViewerExtension2` interface of the viewer.

For example this code is from `SourceViewerDecorationSupport`:

```java
private void showCursorLine() {
    if (fCursorLinePainter == null) {
        if (fSourceViewer instanceof ITextViewerExtension2) {
            fCursorLinePainter = new CursorLinePainter(fSourceViewer);
            fCursorLinePainter.setHighlightColor(getColor(fCursorLinePainterColorKey));

            ITextViewerExtension2 extension = (ITextViewerExtension2) fSourceViewer;
            extension.addPainter(fCursorLinePainter);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, i'm new in RCP, @greg-449.
I have class ATEditor extends TextEditor. (My editor from plugin.xml)
what class shoud i create next and what method to use in my ATEditor class?
I will be very thankful if you answer. This thing will help me understand a lot.

Comment: If you are extending `org.eclipse.ui.editors.text.TextEditor` then `SourceViewerDecorationSupport` is already installed in the editor and what is shown is controlled by the various editor preferences.